# I can't access the res.body of a POST request from the express server in a react/express stack app

Tags: express, request, fetch

This is the server code:

```
app.post("/hello", async function (req, res) {
  let passedInToggleValue = false
  console.log(req.body);
  if (req.body === null || req.body === undefined) {
    console.log("body is empty");
  }
  else if (!req.body.hasOwnProperty('switchBool')) {
    console.log("switchBool is empty");
  }
  else if (req.body.switchBool) {
    passedInToggleValue = true
  }
  const toggleValue = passedInToggleValue ? "on" : "off";
  const resData = `this backend is running and the Testing On/Off Switch is ${toggleValue}`;
  res.send(resData);
});
```

And this is the react code that calls the express API:

```
async function callApi() {
  const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/hello`;
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ switchBool: true })
  };
  const helloStream = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
  const helloText = await helloStream.text();
  console.log(helloText as string);
}
```

But in the terminal, `console.log(req.body);` shows up as undefined and `if (req.body === null || req.body === undefined)` gets triggered and "body is empty" appears in my terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `app.use(express.json());` to the express server code so the relevant section looks like this now:

```
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/hello", async function (req, res) {
  let passedInToggleValue = false
  console.log(req.body);
  if (req.body === null || req.body === undefined) {
    console.log("body is empty");
  }
  else if (!req.body.hasOwnProperty('switchBool')) {
    console.log("switchBool is empty");
  }
  else if (req.body.switchBool) {
    passedInToggleValue = true
  }
  const toggleValue = passedInToggleValue ? "on" : "off";
  const resData = `this backend is running and the Testing On/Off Switch is ${toggleValue}`;
  res.send(resData);
});
```